# MATLAB: colorbar on mapping tool based on point feature

Tags: matlab, plot, mapping

[image]

Hi,

I could able to plot points on the map using geshow function based on value. I need to show a continuous stretched colorbar depicting these values. I don't know how to get so. The colorbar in right doesnot represent these values in the map. Please suggest me how to get so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put your own tick label on the colorbar, for example :

```
colorbar('Ticks',[0, .2, .4 , .6, .8, 1],...
         'TickLabels',{'val_1,'val_2','val_3','val_4','val_5','val_6'})
```

Here, 'Ticks' are values on the colorbar itself, and 'TickLabels' are values (must be represented as strings) that you wish to display instead.

Comment: Thanks for this! but I am not getting the exact color of the shape files, in this case the point features when I am putting colorbar command... Any thought on this?

Comment: Can you post your codes you use to generate figure and colorbar?

Comment: got it ... answer is here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611658/colorbar-for-the-point-shape-file/32620528#32620528